# python cx_freeze error: no commands supplied

Tags: python, cx-freeze

Hi I'm a python newbie trying out cx_Freeze and am obviously doing something wrong. The code is as basic as can be. hello.py is in the c:/python27 folder.

I'm using python 2.7 on Windows 7

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "Test_Run",
    version = "3.1",
    description = "Hello",
    executables = [Executable("hello.py", base = "Win32GUI")])
```

I'm getting the following when executing the script-

```
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

   error: no commands supplied
```

Where am i slipping up?

Danny

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you executing the script from the command line or within the python interpreter? I don't know the particular package you're using, but it looks like it requires another argument you have not provided it.

Comment: Try running it as `python setup.py build`. You can see the different commands available here: http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using `python setup.py` right? If so, that is the error you should get. As the error says, you need to give commands. `build` creates an executable with other mandatory files. `bdist-msi` creates an `.msi` installer. There are other commands, but you can search them easily.